# Why index works so?

Tags: python-3.x

I have `md5sum.txt` file and a python program. Then I want to parse some strings from that file. I don't undestand why my program raises an exception as there should be two elements in the list:

```
import hashlib

checksum_raw = open('F:/md5sum.txt', 'r').read()
cs_list_raw = checksum_raw.split("\n")
cs_list = []
for i in cs_list_raw:
    cs_list.append({
            'sum' : i.split('  ')[0],
            'path' : i.split('  ')[1]
            })
print (cs_list[0])
```

```
D:\newfolder\py_projects>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    'path' : i.split('  ')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But this one works well:

```
import hashlib

checksum_raw = open('F:/md5sum.txt', 'r').read()
cs_list_raw = checksum_raw.split("\n")
cs_list = []
for i in cs_list_raw:
    cs_list.append({
            'sum' : i.split('  ')[0],
            'path' : i.split('  ')[-1]
            })
print (cs_list[0])
```

```
D:\newfolder\py_projects>py test.py
{'sum': 'cde56251d6cae5214227d887dee3bab7', 'path': './pics/red-upperleft.png'}
```

Here are some strings from txt file:

```
cde56251d6cae5214227d887dee3bab7  ./pics/red-upperleft.png
0730e775a72519aaa450a3774fca5f55  ./pics/red-lowerleft.png
cd8aa5e7fa11b1362ef1869ac6b1aa56  ./pics/blue-lowerleft.png
92091902d3ca753bb858d4682b3fc26b  ./pics/logo-50.jpg
461cbc7ff94fdea8008cab34b611abb8  ./pics/blue-upperright.png
9e18ae797773b2677b1b7b86e2aff28d  ./pics/blue-lowerright.png
...
```

Comment: " I don't undestand why my program raises an exception as there should be two elements in the list" well, there isn't. Have you done *any* debugging to see what is actually going on? Even just `print` when there is an error?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sure

Comment: ['cde56251d6cae5214227d887dee3bab7', './pics/red-upperleft.png']

Comment: There is one of i.split('  ') in cs_list_raw

Answer (score 1):

Python indexing works in such a way that -1 maps to the last element in the list. In your case, it looks like there is only one element in the list and hence both the index 0 and -1 map to the same element. You should double-check if all the lines follow the format you specified.

Comment: Of course I know it but there is only two elements int the list, so index 1 has to be the same as -1. And index 0 and -1 don't map to the same element as you see.

Comment: I'm not saying every element in the file has one element. I'm saying there is one value which is causing your program to crash. Try printing the length of the list at each stage and see what the length is when it crashes